# Expansion for $f(x)\in k[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $k$ be a field and let $b(x)\in k[x]$ have $\deg(b)\ge1$. Then each nonzero $f(x)\in k[x]$ has an expansion $f(x)=d_m(x)b(x)^m+\cdots d_j(x)b(x)^j+\cdots+d_0(x)$ for every $d_j(x)=0$ or $\deg(d_j)\lt \deg(b)$.

My textbook proves it by induction, but I have a question about $m$. How to find such $m$ properly.

By division algorithm, $f(x)=g(x)b(x)+d_0(x)$, where $d_0(x)=0$ or $\deg(d_0)\lt \deg(b)$. Since $k[x]$ is an integral domain, $\deg(f)=\deg(g)+\deg(b)$, which means $\deg(g)\lt\deg(f)$. By induction hypothesis, $g(x)=d_m(x)b(x)^{m-1}+\dots+d_1(x)$. Hence, $f(x)=g(x)b(x)+d_0(x)=d_m(x)b(x)^m+\cdots+d_0(x)$.

But why we can say that $g(x)=d_m(x)b(x)^{m-1}+\dots+d_1(x)$ ? I think this $m$ depends on $g$ so it may be some $n$ but it won't get the desire result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, $m$ depends on $f$ (and $b$), and so do the $d_k(x)$.

Since $\deg(d_kb^{k})$ can range from $k\deg b$ to $(k+1)\deg b-1$ (with the one exception when $d_k(x)= 0$) and the highest summand must have degree $\deg f$, we will need $$m=\left\lfloor\frac{\deg f}{\deg b}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: appreciate for your answer. Do you have any suggestions about my writing in inductive step?